# Fabric: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: python, fabric

I have such fabfile.py:

```
from fabric.api import *

def deploy():
    with prefix('source venv/bin/activate'):
        local('pex -r <(cat requirements.txt) . -o app.pex')
```

when I run `$ fab deploy` I get:

```
$ fab deploy
[localhost] local: pex -r <(cat requirements.txt) . -o app.pex
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `source venv/bin/activate && pex -r <(cat requirements.txt) . -o app.pex'

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'pex -r <(cat requirements.txt) . -o app.pex'

Aborting.
```

The command `source venv/bin/activate && pex -r <(cat requirements.txt) . -o app.pex` runs OK in shell. I'm new to Fabric. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`fabric.operations.local()` function](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.local) by default uses `/bin/sh` as the shell to run the command. This basic shell doesn't support all of the syntax that `/bin/bash` would.

Set `shell='/bin/bash'` if you must have access to Bash shell syntax:

```
local('pex -r <(cat requirements.txt) . -o app.pex', shell='/bin/bash'))
```